# How to Filter Multiple Supported Place Types in Google Maps Nearby Search Requests

Tags: javascript

I have seen the code in your site but it's filtering based on only one type like

```
var request = {
location: myplace,
radius: '500',
types: ['Elementary school']
};
```

I need to search multiple types at a time like

```
var request = {
    location: myplace,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['Elementary school','beauty_salon','book_store']
    };
```

Is it possible to filter multiple place types?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var request = {
  location: myplace,
  radius: '500',
  types: 'school|beauty_salon|book_store'
};
```